# Contenedor se sale de pantalla usando Tailwind

Tags: css, css3

Estoy realizando un desarrollo en Vue, pero el tema lo tengo en css (tailwind). Tengo dos maneras de ver el contenido: la primera es en manera de tabla, y la segunda en un contenedor que contiene cards. Cuando la vista se encuentra en la tabla el contenido del section se acomoda bien al width de la pantalla, pero al momento de realizar el cambio de vista el contenedor se sale de la pantalla.

Las fotografías adjuntadas están en vista de desarrollador y como se puede ver en la primer imagen el padding se mantiene, pero en la segunda imagen que es la vista de cards el padding ya no se muestra, dado que, el contenedor está por fuera de la pantalla.

[image: Imagen en vista de tabla]
[image: Imagen en cista de cards]

```
<section class="w-full mt-20">
        <HeaderPage
          titlePage="Festivos"
          showChangeViewType
          showPaginator
          showPrimaryBtn
          labelPrimaryBtn="Agregar festivo"
          @primaryButtonAction="handleShowModal"
          typePrimaryBtn="new"
          v-model:showDataInRowsModel="showRows"
        />
        <main>
          <div class="" v-if="showRows">
            <BaseDataTable :heads="['Nombre', 'Inicio', 'Fin', 'Acciones', '']">
              <template #rowInfo>
                <tr v-for="(item, index) in projectCalendarExceptions" :key="index">
                  <Column :label="item.description" />
                  <Column :label="dateFormat(item.startDate)" />
                  <Column :label="dateFormat(item.finishDate)" />
                  <Column>
                    <template #info>
                      <DeleteButton />
                    </template>
                  </Column>
                  <Column>
                    <template #info>
                      <div>
                        <Btn class="m-auto" />
                      </div>
                    </template>
                  </Column>
                </tr>
              </template>
            </BaseDataTable>
          </div>
          <div class="months__container" v-else>
            <div class="months__container-month" v-for="month in months" :key="month.value">
              <div>
                <div class="title__container">
                  <div class="border"></div>
                  <h1>{{ month.label }}</h1>
                </div>
              </div>
              <div class="container__cards">
                <div v-for="(item, index) in projectCalendarExceptions" :key="index">
                  <BaseCard v-if="Number.parseInt(item.startDate.toString().split('-')[1]) === month.value">
                    <template #content>
                      <div class="card">
                        <div class="container__delete">
                          <DeleteButton />
                        </div>
                        <div class="container__message">
                          <h6>{{ item.description }}</h6>
                          <span>{{ dateFormat(item.startDate) }}</span>
                        </div>
                        <div class="container__detail-btn">
                          <Btn />
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </template>
                  </BaseCard>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </main>
      </section>
```

```css
.months__container {
    background-color: var(--cards-bg-color);
    display: flex;
    padding: 1.25rem;
    border-radius: 0.5rem;
    overflow-x: scroll;
    scrollbar-width: thin;
  }
```